# SQS Queue not receiving all messages

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get an Alexa skill to call a lambda function which sends a message to an SQS Queue. Basically what this guide is doing http://www.cyber-omelette.com/2017/01/alexa-run-script.html

I have the skill and lambda function working, when I execute the skill I get the proper response that's created in the lambda function. However sometimes the Queue gets the message and other times it doesn't, it seems completely random. Is there something that may be causing messages to be dropped/ignored?

Comment: What kind of messages are you providing to your you SQS topic? What is an invocation type of your lambda (sync/async)? Do you have any logs by your lambda (cloud watch)?

Answer (score 1):

In your lambda function, make sure you process ALL the messages received by the lambda function, and not just the first one.
```
def handler(event, context):
    result={}

```
logger.debug(json.dumps(event))
for record in event['Records']:
    message=json.loads(record['body'])
    #do whatever you have to do with the message
```

```